# Remap Comma in Vim

Tags: vim, remap

I would like to remap ctrl-w-w (switch buffer) to the comma.
I tried some combinations with `inoremap` and `remap`, but i can't get it to work.

Any solutions?

Comment: inoremap aims to define a new behavior only in insert mode.
you can prefix by [nvi] remap and no remap to make shortcuts which will depend of the current mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
noremap , <C-w>w
```